# Reindex with Firefox results in timeouts - at the same time Chrome opens admin without problems

Tags: indexing, reindex

I use Firefox as default browser. When I need to reindex data like Catalog URL Rewrites, it completely blocks magento browsing in Firefox. The indexing can take a long time and can result in a timeout, but that's OK for me. When I open another tab, I get the same timeouts, and I cannot do anything else.

I thought this was a magento thing, that while indexing the site became unresponsive. However, when I open the magento admin in Chrome, on the same computer, it works like normal. Minutes later Firefox works again. I can close tabs, reopen the admin dashboard in another tab, but no change.

How does this work and what can I do to get Magento work normally in Firefox again? I've thought of one way, to reindex in Chrome, but I would prefer to have it all working in Firefox.

Update: it seems to work the other way around as well. So reindexing in Chrome makes Chrome unresponsive and Firefox can be used. So that is a workaround, but I don't understand why you can't do this in one browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open some page or start some process (reindex) you can't do another actions in current session. Each browser start own session.

You can try use [Fast Asynchronous Reindex](http://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-asynchronous-reindex.html) for move reindex process to cron or run shell command for reindex `php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url_rewrite`